# python import module from different folder

Tags: python

I have the following folder structure:

[image]

In this `process_file.py`  script I want to be able to import the class `process_things.py`  which is in the classes folder.  Tried following method 3 in this blog but it doesn't seem to work:
https://blog.finxter.com/python-how-to-import-modules-from-another-folder/

I have noticed that if I put the `process_file.py` file outside the jobs folder and run `from classes import process_file` then it works fine, but ideally I really want the file to be in the jobs folder.

Answer (score 1):

did you check sys lib? a quick way like this :

```
    import sys
    sys.path.append('/path_to_your_project_folder/src/databricks/classes')
    import process_things
```

Comment: yeah that works but I want to stick to method 3 if possible